# C++ Box2d memory managememnt / garbage collection

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, box2d

Does Box2d has a reference counter to remove unused bodies and its fixtures automatically in C++ version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by 'unused'... bodies remain in the world until you call DestroyBody. Calling DestroyBody will free the memory the body was using, along with all the fixtures and joints it had. Check out the Box2D manual and search for "memory" and "DestroyBody".

Bodies will also be freed when you delete the world itself, in which case you don't need to call DestroyBody for them.

Comment: By `unused` I mean the reference counter on that body is 0. But seems Box2D has not reference counting. (E.g. cocos2d defines autorelease objects. If you don't use the autorelease object it will be garbage collected.)

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. While technically you could wrap a b2Body* in your own class if you wanted to make use of autopointer features, and make the destructor call DestroyBody, I'm not sure if it would be very useful. The existence of a body means there is a physical thing in the world that can collide and interact with other stuff - you would probably want to have better control over when such objects enter and leave your world. I think it's better to make a deliberate call to DestroyBody to remove them.